# Twitter bootstrap dropdown active nav creating a white area and looks strange

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, nav

I've looked at this for a number of hours now and can't figure out what is going on. Any help would be much appreciated thank you.  It is a very strange problem and rather than going into detail I thought it best to just show you, so please find below a link to problem, currently on the development page of my website.

http://dev.cccit.co.uk/about-us/our-team/

As you can see the active dropdown seems to work along with the header being active in the nav bar as well, however when highlighting the nav select it is making the header appear darker and also not selecting the whole box (missing out the information section).  It is probably easier to just see for yourself.... hover over About Us in the nav bar and you will see.

I thought initially this might be css related.... there is a separate css file for color selection which I have changed every option without any affect, and what makes me think this won't help is the strange way in which the whole menu is not changing when you hover.  Please find a copy of the code below, bear in mind I'm using php for this section, but it also does the same thing regardless, so I have also changed the header for "Support" so that you can see it is doing the same thing.

I thought someone may have come across the same thing, if you need any more information or files, then please get in touch.  Thank you in advance

`div class="container">

```
            <div id="nav-wrapper">
            <div class="navbar">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="buttons-container">
                        </div>
                        <div class="nav-collapse">
                            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                                <li class="single"><a href="../index.php">HOME
                                        <i></i>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li <?php if($pageName == "About Us")echo " class='dropdown active' ";?> class="dropdown">
                                    <a href='/about-us'>
                                        ABOUT US<i></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li <?php if($pageMetaTitle == "Our Team")echo " class='active' ";?>><a href="/about-us/our-team">Our Team</a></li>
                                        <li <?php if($pageMetaTitle == "Philosophy")echo " class='active' ";?>><a href="/about-us/philosophy">Philosophy</a></li>
                                        <li <?php if($pageMetaTitle == "FAQs")echo " class='active' ";?>><a href="/about-us/faqs">FAQs</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown active">
                                    <a href="/support">
                                        SUPPORT<i>IT support for business</i>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="/support/support-packages">Support Packages</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="/support/sla">Service Level Agreements</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="/support/faqs">FAQs</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the custom background colors you set have for the `<i>` tags.

Noticing the hover effects on Firebug, the colors don't match the hover effects of the parent element.